# SocketIO - detect and count connections

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm counting connections for same user. Because I want events I write in disconnect to run when client closes all tabs of browser. So I make simple thing like this (I dont want to use sessions).

client:

```
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

    /* ------------------------------------- */

    socket.emit('status',{'mode':online,'user':userID});
```

app.js:

```
    const server = require('http').createServer();
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);

    /* ------------------------------------- */

    var count = 0;

    io.on('connection',function(socket){

        socket.on('status',function(response){

        count++;

        socket.on('disconnect',function(){

        count--;

        if(count==0) { other events }

        }
    }
}
```

My question is; How can I set count value as specific for `response.user` ?
It works with one user, but not working if multi users.

(response.user contains ID number of the user)